# Sending emails?

Tags: email

Hi i saw a post explaining how to send emails in python. But my problem is finding a server that will send my email on.. I read about setting one up and i read that it is a complicated process.. Can anyone help me find a server or give me a tip to set one up myself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the SMTP of your ISP and it should work just fine.
Otherwize you can use gmail/yahoo's smtp (and others), but it (almost) always requires you to be identified, to avoid open relay smtp (of course to avoid spam). This is not a difficult task with libraries.

[here](http://kutuma.blogspot.com/2007/08/sending-emails-via-gmail-with-python.html) is an example of python script to send mail via gmail.